# How to solve $\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right)^3\left(-\dfrac{3}{5}\right)^2$

Tags: arithmetic

I need help in solving this problem (sorry I didn't know how to write it on here).

Comment: I think the question is evaluating $(5/3)^3(-3/5)^2$ into simplest terms.

Comment: Usually an equation needs an equals sign. Do you mean $\frac 53 x^3 = - \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2$?

Comment: 404 calculus/linear algebra.

Comment: Sorry It's not an equation

Comment: Do you know what powers are? Do you know how to multiply rational numbers together? Do you know that negative times negative is positive? If the answer to all three of these questions is yes, then you have all the tools you need to to simplify the expression. All you have to do is use them.

Comment: Yeah thanks i figured it out

Comment: Why all the dowmvotes? Seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: This is a question about skill, not a mathematical question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right)^3*\left(-\dfrac{3}{5}\right)^2$ =  $\left(\dfrac{5^3}{3^3}\right)*\left(\dfrac{(-3)^2}{5^2}\right)$

Another hint:

To multiply two fractions, you can multiply the two numerators by each other, and the two denominators by each other to get the new numerator and denominator.

[Here is a resource you should work through](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**$$\left(\frac 53 \right)^3 \left(-\frac 35 \right)^2=\left(\frac 53 \right)\left(\frac 53 \right)^2 \left(-\frac 35 \right)^2=\left(\frac 53 \right)\left(\frac 53 \cdot-\frac 35 \right)^2$$
Can you simplify $\displaystyle \frac 53 \cdot -\frac 35$?

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align}\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right)^3\left(\dfrac{-3}{5}\right)^2 & = \left(\dfrac{5^3}{3^3}\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{(-1)^2 3^2}{5^2}\right) & \text{by commutativity of exponents} \\ ~ & = \dfrac{(-1)^2 5^1}{3^1} & \text{by associativity of exponents} \\ ~ & = \dfrac{5}{3} & \text{by }(-1)^2=1, a^1 = a \end{align}$